# Is it ok to access a static list variable value by class name which is a readonly static list?

Tags: java, static

Here is my code.

```
public class PropertyLoader {

    private Properties appProperties;

    /**
     * The instance.
     */
    private static PropertyLoader inst = null;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new property data loader.
     */
    private PropertyLoader() {
        try
        {
            appProperties = new Properties();
            appProperties.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static PropertyLoader getInstance() {
        if (inst == null) {
            inst = new PropertyLoader();
        }
            return inst;
        }
    }

    public String getPropertyAPP(String key) {
        return appProperties.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

Synchronization is needed for the `getPropertyAPP` method: it is a singleton, so many threads can access the same instance simultaneously and call it.

Can anyone suggest me the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following solution

```
public class PropertyLoader {

        private Properties appProperties;

    /** The instance. */
    private static PropertyLoader inst = null;

    static{
        inst = new PropertyLoader();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new property data loader.
     */
    private PropertyLoader() {
            try
            {
                appProperties = new Properties();
                appProperties.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties"));
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public static PropertyLoader getInstance() {
        return inst;
    }


    public String getPropertyAPP(String key) {
        return appProperties.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution, which is also thread safe, is to use static initialisation to initialise a static field.

```
public class AppProperties {
    private static final Properties appProperties;
    static {
        try {
            appProperties = new Properties();
            appProperties.load(AppProperties.class
                      .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties"));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return appProperties.getProperty(key);
    }

    public String get(String key, String defaultValue) {
        return appProperties.getProperty(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Peter, the IOException would surely lead to a broken application?

Comment: @MrWiggles unless the defaults are sensible. Otherwise I would wrap the IOE with an AssertionError

Answer (score 0):

You have a massive race condition happening in your `getInstance()` method.  If more than one threads call `getInstance()` at the same time you will create multiple instances and assign them in turn to the static variable.  Considering what you're doing here this won't cause any logic problems, but does mean you're doing more work than necessary.

I recommend you do some reading about the Singleton pattern, why it's bad, and how to implement it in a safe way in Java.

But in short, don't use the Singleton pattern, it's hideously broken and will make any code that uses this object tightly-coupled and will inhibit your ability to do any kind of isolated testing.

Comment: Perhaps you could suggest an alternative to the `Singleton` pattern for `Properties`. BTW: The pattern is not broken - many implementations of it in Java are broken.

Comment: The Singleton pattern as presented here with classes knowing where to locate the Singleton *is* broken- Eric Gamma has even stated it should never have been in the GoF book.  I would recommend instantiating it at application startup by hand or with a DI framework and injecting it where necessary.

Comment: yes but i have called get instance in synchronized environment means on    contextInitialized  so , still static block initialization is proffered. I was not sure about getPropertyAPP method whether race condition occurs there or not. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues with your code:

(a) Are you sure you need lazy initialisation? The cost of initialisation must be noticeable and the chance that the resource is never used must be non-zero. Also: it may be preferable to fail during program start rather than at some indeterminate moment later when the resource is first accessed. This really depends on your application.

(b) One way of implementing the lazy initialisation is using the correct version of double checked locking (the volatile keyword is essential):

```
private static volatile PropertyLoader inst;
...
public static PropertyLoader getInstance() {
    if (inst == null) {
        synchronized(PropertyLoader.class) {
            if (inst == null) {
                inst = new PropertyLoader();
            }
        }
    }
    return inst;
}
```

This wikipedia article explains why this works (as of Java 5 but nore before): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

(c) Catching exceptions and simply logging them is plain wrong under most circumstances. In your case, no property would ever be returned from getPropertyAPP. This may be ok if the presence of the properties is clearly declared to be optional.